# How can I fix this compile error, when attempting to compile sass using Prepros and Gumby?

Tags: css, web, windows-7, sass, prepros

I am using windows 7 to compile .scss with an application known as Prepros. (http://alphapixels.com/prepros/ ). I also downloaded the Gumby Framework(http://gumbyframework.com/) into my document root directory of localhost web-server. My goal is to use the gumby framework along with Prepros.

When I attempt to compile the scss file, I am receiving the following error:

```
Syntax error: Undefined operation: "power(golden_ratio(), 1) times 16px".
    on line 52 of Z:/Ampps/www/Gumby-master/sass/extensions/modular-scale/stylesheets/_modular-scale.scss
    from line 23 of Z:\Ampps\www\Gumby-master\sass\gumby.scss Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Also, if it is helpful, this is the config.rb file contained within the folder www\Gumby-master :

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
# Tell compass where to find local extensions
# If you followed directions and ran 'gem install modular-scale' comment the next two     lines out:
extensions_dir = "sass/extensions"
Compass::Frameworks.register('modular-scale', :path => File.expand_path("#  {extensions_dir}/modular-scale"))
# Uncomment these to use regular Ruby gems.
# require 'modular-scale'
# require 'sassy-math'
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command   line) :nested or :expanded or :compact or :compressed:
output_style = :compact
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors.     Uncomment:
line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

Lastly,I reviewed [this](https://plus.google.com/111923336570033452384/posts) thread, but I did not find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION:** I tried several things to fix this, and I am not absolutely which of them were responsible for fixing it.

- Install ruby development kit
- Install rails
- Install gumby-framework gem (https://github.com/jorgecoca/gumby-framework)
- Verify that the modular-scale gem is installed ( https://github.com/Team-Sass/modular-scale)
- Use Advanced Prepros options to use third-party compass plugins (http://alphapixels.com/prepros/docs/sass-compass.html) (**NOTE:** initially I made the mistake of giving this path `C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems`, when in fact I realized I must provide this one `C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe`, just like in the picture in the Prepros manual.)

-as stated [in this thread](https://plus.google.com/111923336570033452384/posts), I opened my compass config.rb and commented out `Compass::Frameworks.register('modular-scale', :path => File.expand_path("#{extensions_dir}/modular-scale"))`, and un-commented `#require 'modular-scale'` and `#require 'sassy-math'`.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this exact same issue. So I would like to share things which I did.

Gumby framework README.md file states "*Note: Please use modular scale 1.0.6, 2.x has not been integrated yet*". Make sure the version of modular scale installed on your machine is 1.0.6!

How to check?

1. Let's assume the location of your Ruby installation is "C:\Ruby200".
2. Go to C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems. In this directory, you will see all the gems that were installed on the machine. (You should see sass, compass, modular-scale among others)
3. Make sure it says "modular-scale-1.0.6". If it doesn't, then delete the version you have over there. If you see multiple sassy-math over here, don't worry. We just want one modular-scale on the machine!

How to install Modular Scale v1.0.6?

1. Run gem install modular-scale v 1.0.6

What else to watch out for?

Like Daniel said, open your config.rb. Make sure you have the following lines in it!

```
#Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'modular-scale'
require 'sassy-math'
```

Whatever you do, don't have the following code in your config.rb file. For this code to truly work, you have to have a directory called extensions in your sass directory, and you have to copy all the modular-scale binaries into that directory.

```
extensions_dir = "sass/extensions"
Compass::Frameworks.register('modular-scale', :path => File.expand_path("#{extensions_dir}/modular-scale"))
```

If you run into any other problems and somehow manage to solve it, please do add your answer here! The entire installation experience is terrible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Parth Shah -- that worked for me. But the command to install modular-scale 1.0.6 is actually:

gem install modular-scale -v 1.0.6

He missed the hyphen before the v.

BTW as per this date, there has been a Gumby update so that Gumby supposedly now works with these compass, sass and modular-scale versions -- see below for install commands.

gem install compass -v0.12.4,
gem install sass -v3.2.18
gem install modular-scale -v2.0.4

I am still running the older versions but this update has been confirmed by other Gumby users.